# Nothing happens on JSP when calling JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

I write a web application and try to understand how Ajax works.
Nothing happens when I try to select a category and no errors are occured.

JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/all.css" />                  
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var categoryName;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function doAjaxPost(){
            categoryName = $('#selectCategory').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "Get",
                url : "loadProducts",
                data : "Category selected =" + categoryName,
                success : function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#selectCategory").on("change", doAjaxPost());
</script>


<title>Waiter</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Waiter's page </h3>
<h2>
Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
<a href="/logout" class="btn-on">Logout</a>
</h2>
<br>
<c:if test="${!empty productCategoriesList}">
    <spring:message code="label.category" />
    <select id="selectCategory" name="productCategory">
        <option value=" "></option>
        <c:forEach items="${productCategoriesList}" var="productCategory">
            <option value=${productCategory.id}>${productCategory.productType}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</c:if>

<div id = "product">
    <spring:message code="label.product" />
    <select>
        <option value = ""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadProducts")
public @ResponseBody String loadProducts(@RequestParam("categoryName") 
String categoryName){
    System.out.println(categoryName);
    String str = "Category selected: " + categoryName;
    return str;
}
```

What should be done in order to make this function work?

Comment: Try moving your `on('change')` function inside your `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: @Lixus Tried it, but got the same error. If I remove "onchange= doAjaxPost()" from my select tag - error is not shown, but nothing happens as well.

Comment: Update your question so that we can see what you have done.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate issues:

1. You're trying to use an `onxyz`-attribute-style handler in the HTML. Those can only access **global** functions. (It's one of the many reasons not to use them.) Your `doAjaxPost` function is not global.
2. Your code trying to hook it up with jQuery's `on` is at global scope, and so it, too, would need `doAjaxPost` to be global.

You *could* fix this by making it global (moving the declaration outside your `ready` callback), but globals are a Bad Thing™.

Instead, move your `on` call *into* the `ready` handler and remove the `onchange="doAjaxCall()"` in the HTML:

```
var categoryName;
$(document).ready(function () {
    function doAjaxPost(){
        categoryName = $('#selectCategory').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "Get",
            url : "loadProducts",
            data : "Category selected =" + categoryName,
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    }
    $("#selectCategory").on("change", doAjaxPost());    }); // ** Moved**
```

and

```html
<select id="selectCategory" name="productCategory">
<!-- No onchange --------------------------------^  -->
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer.
Did it, and the error dissapeared. But as I understand 
some alert window has to appear to show that  a response is returned correctly. But nothing is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Place `$("#selectCategory").on("change", doAjaxPost());` inside `document.ready()`
call back function